# How much RAM Does Ubuntu use?

Tags: laptop, ram, yoga-2

I have a Yoga 2 11( model 20428) and Win8.1 takes about 2 of my 4gb of RAM to run.

How much RAM will Ubuntu use to run.

This is a secondary laptop, for movie watching, school work, websurfing and etc.

nothing too hardcore.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Ubuntu wiki, Ubuntu requires a minimum of 1024 MB of RAM, but 2048 MB is recommended for daily use.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

You may also consider a version of Ubuntu running an alternate desktop environment requiring less RAM, such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu. Lubuntu is said to run fine with 512 MB of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu Desktop

The following covers Ubuntu and Edubuntu:

### Minimum

- [Trusty Tahr (14.04 64-bit)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements)

  - 384 MB of RAM
  - 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
  - 5 GB of hard-drive space
  - VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
  - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

### Recommended

- [Trusty Tahr (14.04 64-bit)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements)

  - 1 GB of RAM
  - Dual Core processor
  - 10 GB of hard-drive space or SSD (the more hard disk capacity, [the better](https://superuser.com/a/21493/235569))
  - Any graphics card with [OpenGL 1.4 support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DemystifyingUnityGraphicsHardwareRequirements) (All GPUs released today by either NVidia, AMD or Intel; GPUs released by NVidia and AMD over the last 5 years; GPUs released by Intel after the GMA 950)
  - Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
  - Internet access is helpful

(Requirements for Trusty hasn't been updated in official Release Notes, so, it's safe to presume that all the Desktop versions of Ubuntu still have the same requirements as Precise/Saucy)